# Closed form for x-ray projection of a cube on a plane

Tags: geometry, projection

Imagine a cube of side $d$ positioned at $\mathbf{x}_0 = [x_0, y_0, z_0]$ in a 3-dimensional space. Consider a scan plane $P$ with normal vector $\mathbf{n} = [n_x, n_y, n_z]$ (like in the following figure). We are interested in finding the projection of the cube on the scan plane. The projection value at each point $\mathbf{p} = [x, y, z]$ on the plane is the length of the line segment going through $\mathbf{p}$ parallel to $\mathbf{n}$ and restricted inside the cube (quantity $l$ in the figure).

I am interested in finding a *closed form* solution for the problem.

[Example Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBG0a.png)

**What I have done so far:**

I can find the intersection of the line passing through $\mathbf{p}$ and parallel to $\mathbf{n}$ with all 6 sides of the cube. This gives me 6 points in space. Then I check which ones of these 6 intersection points lie on the cube boundaries. At most two points do. The Euclidean distance of these two points is the solution. This solution works, but is not scalable for implementation; imagine trying to find this for millions of points on the scan plane. That's why I am looking for a closed form solution to make my implementation faster.

Comment: What leads you to believe that there is a closed-form solution? Some case-checking seems unavoidable. A line-plane intersection isn’t terribly expensive: using homogeneous coordinates, it can be compute with two dot products, two scalar-vector multiplications, a vector addition and three divisions. You could, I suppose, preprocess the cube’s shadow into triangular regions tagged with the pair of planes to intersect, but I’m not convinced that determining the correct region for a pixel is significantly more efficient than computing all of the intersections and culling.

Comment: Project the vertices and edges of the cube into your plane first. They will divide your plane into a number of (usually quadrilateral) sections. For each section, you can express the function by an equation. Depending on your needs, you could do all points in each section together before moving on to the next section.